# Export layer coordinates - Sketch 3

Tags: sketch-app

How can you export the (x,y) coordinates of a layer with the rest of CSS properties? 
I can't export position values even placing them at 0,0

Comment: Unfortunately that's currently not possible with Sketch. Notice that the dimensions of the element are not exported either.

Comment: I personally find the position information to be kinda useless. For example: Photoshop gives you the position, but it uses absolute positioning. Since you don't normally position every element like that, this information is pretty much useless. It just won't play well with other elements. Even if PS gave me the position in margins or paddings instead, I would most likely have to adjust them anyways because it's very likely that I have some padding in the parent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *huptur* said, css-sizes and and css-positions are not exported.
Maybe it's not interesting for *Joonas* but it's important for me (and many other people, for sure).

Hope It can be done in future versions.